# Remove a field from details in Crystal Reports fo SUM

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is my crystal report PAY_DETAILS data field.Here I need to remove/suppress the CBS field and its value when I am getting the total.

```
Amount      Earn_Type
    -----------------------
        100       ER006
        200       ER007
        300       ER009
        400       ER003
        500       ER004
        1000      CBS
        600       ARS
    -----------------------
       2100       Total
```

So when the view should be as follows.I tried it with suppressing the field with the suppressing condition

```
if({PAY_DETAILS.EARN_TYPE}="CBS")
```

But even it hides it comes to the Total

```
    Amount      Earn_Type
    -----------------------
        100       ER006
        200       ER007
        300       ER009
        400       ER003
        500       ER004
        600       ARS
    -----------------------
       3100       Total
```

Comment: couldn't understand.... you want to hide in report or you just need to exclude during the sum

Comment: Hide it and exclude during the sum

Answer (score 0):

create a formula maybe call it Amount

```
if {PAY_DETAILS.EARN_TYPE}="CBS" then {valuefield} else 0
```

place that in the details and creat a total from that instead of the database field.

In your suppression area use

```
{@Amount} = 0
```